# DOM parsing a file- input shown is not ordered

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I have the following xml file now, it is named "Weather 2.xml":

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<weather> 
       <forecast_information>
                                    <city data="Pittsford, NY" />
                                    <postal_code data="14534" /> 
                                    <forecast_date data="2015-03-12" /> 
                                    <unit_system data="US" />
        </forecast_information>
        <current_conditions> 
                                    <condition data = "Mostly Cloudy" /> 
                                   <temp_f data ="42" /> 
                                   <wind_condition data="Wind: NW at 7 mph" /> 
        </current_conditions> 
        <forecast_conditions>
                                    <day_of_week data="Sat" /> 
                                    <low data="32"/> 
                                   <high data = "45" />
                                   <condition data="Rain and Snow" />
         </forecast_conditions>
         <forecast_information> 
                                    <city data= "Rochester, NY" /> 
                                    <postal_code data="14623" /> 
                                   <forecast_date data= "2015-03-12" /> 
                                   <unit_system data="US" /> 
         </forecast_information>
          <current_conditions> 
                                    <condition data="Partly Cloudy" /> 
                                    <temp_f data="40" />
                                    <wind_condition data="Wind: St at 3.5 mph" />
           </current_conditions> 
           <forecast_conditions>
                                     <day_of_week data="Mon" /> 
                                     <low data="30" /> 
                                     <high data="40" />
                                     <condition data="Bright and Sunny" />
            </forecast_conditions> 
   </weather>
```

I have changed my program the way it is coded in the following way:

```
 public class DomParserDemo {
 public static void main(String[] args){

  try { 
     File inputFile = new File("Weather 2.xml");
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory 
        = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
     doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
     System.out.println("Root element :" 
        + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
     NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("forecast_information");
     System.out.println("----------------------------");
     for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" 
           + nNode.getNodeName());
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
           Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
           System.out.println("City : " +eElement.getElementsByTagName("city").item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data"));
           System.out.println("Postal_Code : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("postal_code").item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data"));
           System.out.println("Forecast date : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("forecast_date").item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data"));
           System.out.println("Unit System : " + eElement .getElementsByTagName("unit_system") .item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data"));
           }

        NodeList nList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("current_conditions");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        for (temp = 0; temp < nList1.getLength(); temp++) {
           Node nNode1 = nList1.item(temp);
           System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" 
              + nNode1.getNodeName());
           if (nNode1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
               Element eElement1 = (Element) nNode1;
           System.out.println("Condition : " + eElement1 .getElementsByTagName("condition") .item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data"));
           System.out.println("Temperature : " + eElement1 .getElementsByTagName("temp_f").item(0) .getAttributes().getNamedItem("data"));

           System.out.println("Wind Condition : " + eElement1 .getElementsByTagName("wind_condition").item(0) .getAttributes().getNamedItem("data"));

           }


           NodeList nList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("forecast_conditions");
           System.out.println("----------------------------");
           for (temp = 0; temp < nList2.getLength(); temp++) {
              Node nNode2 = nList2.item(temp);
              System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" 
                 + nNode2.getNodeName());
              if (nNode2.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                 Element eElement2 = (Element) nNode2;
           System.out.println("Day of week : " + eElement2 .getElementsByTagName("day_of_week") .item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data"));
           System.out.println("Low : " + eElement2 .getElementsByTagName("low") .item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data"));
           System.out.println("High: " + eElement2 .getElementsByTagName("high") .item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data"));
           System.out.println("Condition: " + eElement2 .getElementsByTagName("condition") .item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data"));

           }

     }
  } }}
  catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
```

tHE OUTPUT SHOWN IS NOT IN ORDER & SOME OF THE FIELDS ARE MISSING:

```
  Root element :weather
  ----------------------------

  Current Element :forecast_information
  City : data="Pittsford, NY"
  Postal_Code : data="14534"
  Forecast date : data="2015-03-12"
  Unit System : data="US"
  ----------------------------

  Current Element :current_conditions
  Condition : data="Mostly Cloudy"
  Temperature : data="42"
  Wind Condition : data="Wind: NW at 7 mph"
  ----------------------------

  Current Element :forecast_conditions
  Day of week : data="Sat"
  Low : data="32"
  High: data="45"
  Condition: data="Rain and Snow"

  Current Element :forecast_conditions
  Day of week : data="Mon"
  Low : data="30"
  High: data="40"
  Condition: data="Bright and Sunny"
```

I WANT THE CODE TO DISPLAY IT IN ORDER: THE FORECAST INFORMATION, CURRENT CONDITION AND FORECAST CONDITION;TWICE AS THERE ARE 2 RECORDS FOR EACH IN THE XML FILE

Comment: Please don't use CAPITALIZATION WHEN IT IS OT REQUIRED.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for not getting all data printed : You have used the int variable temp same across all the for loops

In Detail: The for loop int variable temp is initialized in each loop forecast_information, current_conditions and forecast_conditions. When the for loop for forecast_conditions is executed twice the int variable temp value is 2 and hence the for loops for forecast_information and current_conditions are not executed.

Solution:
Have seperate variables for each for loops.
Nested for loops will result in printing the current_conditions and forecast_conditions data more than once, so you have to restructure your code to avoid nested for loops.